# Adobe Illustrator / Rhinoceros custom object select

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-scripting

I'm using both AI and Rhino. I've got a file that's got over a thousand small circles that are nested inside other curves all over the file randomly. I want to select them all and group them in either Rhino or AI.

How can this be done? I'm thinking programmatically, like `select_if{ 0.05cm <= a && a <= 0.10}`. Of course this string of code is just pseudocode to give you the gist of what I'm after assuming there is an "under the hood" approach to graphic design vis-a-vis AI or Rhino.

Comment: What is 'Rhino'?

Comment: It is, quite simply, amazing: https://www.rhino3d.com

Comment: @Woolf, the rhino engine was amazing in 90's today its just prety medicore

Comment: Do all these small circles have the same fill or stroke which is different than other objects? What's the layer stack look like? Illustrator doesn't have any inherent means of selecting by size. No clue about Rhino.

Answer (score 1):

You can script Illustrator using JavaScript with the Extend Script API provided by Adobe. But that's beyond my Illustrator-fu. You can learn more about the Extend Script toolkit and API for Illustrator here: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/illustrator/scripting.html